# AWS CloudFormation, refer parameters in tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to apply a set of tags to a SNS topic and one of the tags refer to a parameter.  Given below is an extract of the template I have (I have reduced the tags to highlight my problem)

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Deploys resources 

Parameters:
  MyParameter:
    Type: String
    Default: "testEnvironment"

Mappings:
  Mp1:
    Mp1-1:
      tags:
        - Key: key1
          Value: !Ref MyParameter

Resources:
  snsTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: snsTopic
      TopicName: snsTopic
      Tags: !FindInMap [Mp1, Mp1-1, tags]
```

Now when I run this on CloudFormation I get the following error:

`Every entry in list for property Tags must be a map of String`

Does someone know how to fix this or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't define Mappings in this way. [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html) clearly say that:

> You **cannot include parameters**, pseudo parameters, or intrinsic functions in the Mappings section.

So your Mapping should be

```
Mappings:

  Mp1:
    Mp1-1:
      tags:
        - Key: key1
          Value: MyValue # <-- No !Ref here, just fixed string
```

If you want to `!Ref` MyParameter, then you should put it in the `AWS::SNS::Topic` resource.

```
Resources:
  snsTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: snsTopic
      TopicName: snsTopic
      Tags: 
        - Key: key1
          Value: !Ref MyParameter
```

Comment: This does not help me, the `MyValue` comes from outside as part of the cloudformation cli command, so if I want to include a tag value based on a command line parameter how do I do it?

Comment: You have to change your template and put tags in the resource, not mapping. There you can reference parameters.

Comment: ok, but some of my tags are common to the rest of the resources as well, so if I follow this I will have to duplicate them, is there anyway to define the common tags at the mappings and then merge them with the additional tags under the resource using an intrinsic function or something

Comment: CloudFormation is not a programming language, so it has a lot of limitations. If you really want to do it without copying and pasting, then maybe creating basic find-and-replace [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) could be worth considering.